Reload nginx config in container causes restart
I'm trying to use nginx as a reverse proxy in a Kubernetes setup. We are required to verify client certificates against CRL-files, and a sidecar container is responsible for updating the CRL's.
My idea was to use nginx -s reload to update the configuration in the nginx-container, but for some reason the container starts a completely new master-process and since the listen-ports aren't available it shuts down after a few seconds.
It looks like the reload is behaving correctly at first, the logs describes a graceful shutdown and starting new workers and suddenly the container is stopped.
I've tried the debugging version with no luck, I can't find any root cause to the behavior.
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: can not modify /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf (read-only file system?)
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2024/05/22 06:49:37 [notice] 88#88: using the "epoll" event method
2024/05/22 06:49:37 [notice] 88#88: nginx/1.26.0
2024/05/22 06:49:37 [notice] 88#88: built by gcc 12.2.0 (Debian 12.2.0-14) 
2024/05/22 06:49:37 [notice] 88#88: OS: Linux 5.14.0-284.50.1.el9_2.x86_64
2024/05/22 06:49:37 [notice] 88#88: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2024/05/22 06:49:37 [notice] 88#88: start worker processes
2024/05/22 06:49:37 [notice] 88#88: start worker process 108
2024/05/22 06:49:37 [notice] 88#88: start worker process 109
2024/05/22 06:49:37 [notice] 88#88: start worker process 110
2024/05/22 06:49:37 [notice] 88#88: start worker process 111
2024/05/22 06:49:37 [notice] 88#88: start worker process 112
2024/05/22 06:49:37 [notice] 88#88: start worker process 113
2024/05/22 06:49:37 [notice] 88#88: start worker process 114
2024/05/22 06:49:37 [notice] 88#88: start worker process 115
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 88#88: signal 1 (SIGHUP) received from 123, reconfiguring
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 88#88: reconfiguring
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 88#88: using the "epoll" event method
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 88#88: start worker processes
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 88#88: start worker process 124
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 88#88: start worker process 125
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 88#88: start worker process 126
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 88#88: start worker process 127
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 88#88: start worker process 128
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 88#88: start worker process 129
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 88#88: start worker process 130
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 88#88: start worker process 131
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 110#110: gracefully shutting down
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 109#109: gracefully shutting down
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 110#110: exiting
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 109#109: exiting
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 108#108: gracefully shutting down
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 108#108: exiting
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 111#111: gracefully shutting down
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 111#111: exiting
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 112#112: gracefully shutting down
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 112#112: exiting
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 113#113: gracefully shutting down
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 113#113: exiting
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 115#115: gracefully shutting down
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 115#115: exiting
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 114#114: gracefully shutting down
2024/05/22 06:49:56 [notice] 114#114: exiting

I'm using nginx:1.26.0, and I haven't added any scripts in the docker-entrypoint.d-dir.
We are using a custom uid/gid range, and I´m not able to specify the default 101/101 uid/gid due to security restrictions.
I'm running my workloads in an Openshift 4 setup.

The container restart was caused by a OOMKilled event, and after raising memory limits everything works fine.
